# How does this SQL query translate to JPQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

I´m trying to get accustomed to JPQL, but i´m already stuck. How does this:

`SELECT * FROM Table_a INNER JOIN Table_b USING (Table_bID) Where Table_b.Column_a LIKE 'somestring'`

translate to JPQL ? I would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a from EntityMappedToTableA 
inner join fetch a.entityMappedToTableB b
where b.fieldMappedOnColumnA like :someString
```

For this to work, you must have a relationship (I assume it is a ManyToOne, since there seems to be several rows in table A which have the ID of table B) from EntityMappedToTableA to EntityMappedToTableB :

```
@Entity
public class EntityMappedToTableA {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Table_bID")
    private EntityMappedToTableB entityMappedToTableB;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: My mapping is ` @JoinColumn(name = "VaterID", referencedColumnName = "VaterID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Vaeter vaeter;`.  `createQuery("SELECT k FROM Kinder k INNER JOIN FETCH k.vaeter  WHERE k.vaterName LIKE :vname");` is the query. Doing this i get an exception where " unknown state or association field [vaterName] of class [kms3.entities.Kinder]." As i see it, i am trying to read "vaterName" in entity "Kinder" instead of entity "Vaeter". Is the error in the query or the mapping?

Comment: It's an error in the query. I misread your SQL query and made a mistake in the translation. I'll fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, but it still doesn´t work. I´ve tried following: "SELECT k FROM Kinder k INNER JOIN FETCH k.vaeter vat WHERE vat.vaterName LIKE :vname" , but i get an exception on the "unknown token vat". Without the alias "vat" it can´t find vaterName. I have a major flaw in my understanding this join fetch business.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The "fetch" was actually the error this time around. the code that worked was "select a from EntityMappedToTableA 
inner join a.entityMappedToTableB b
where b.fieldMappedOnColumnA like :someString". Thank you for your help.